# Getting error with previously supported Optional type requirements on a function declaration (same-type, error in Swift 6)

Tags: swift, generics, swift-optionals

This currently works, but in xcode-beta it is now showing a warning:

`Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Value' non-generic; this is an error in Swift 6`

```swift
func getUDValue<Value, R>(_ key: String, _ defaultValue: Value) -> Value
where Value == R?, R: RawRepresentable
{
    guard let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? R.RawValue else {
        return defaultValue
    }
    return R(rawValue: rawValue) ?? defaultValue
}
```

I understand what it is saying, but trying to remove the `Value == R?, R: RawRepresentable` has proven difficult as the `R` is needed to access the `RawValue` and `init(rawValue:)` behind the `Optional<RawRepresentable>`

Interestingly enough, I got this structure from Apple's own AppStorage initializer for optional RawRepresentables: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage/init(_:store:)-6aj8x

If this is soon to be an error, does anyone know how to accomplish this in the new world?

### Update:

My current solution was to move these methods into a struct that provides the generic  label. See here:

```swift
private struct UserDefaultsWrapper<Value> {
    static nonisolated func getValue(_ key: String, _ defaultValue: Value) -> Value
    where Value: RawRepresentable
    {
        guard let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Value.RawValue else {
            return defaultValue
        }
        return Value(rawValue: rawValue) ?? defaultValue
    }

    static nonisolated func getValue<R>(_ key: String, _ defaultValue: Value) -> Value
    where Value == R?, R: RawRepresentable
    {
        guard let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? R.RawValue else {
            return defaultValue
        }
        return R(rawValue: rawValue) ?? defaultValue
    }

    static nonisolated func getValue(_ key: String, _ defaultValue: Value) -> Value
    where Value: UserDefaultsPropertyListValue
    {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue
    }

    static nonisolated func getValue<R>(_ key: String, _ defaultValue: Value) -> Value
    where Value == R?, R: UserDefaultsPropertyListValue
    {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? R ?? defaultValue
    }

    static nonisolated func setValue(_ key: String, _ newValue: Value)
    where Value: RawRepresentable
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: key)
    }

    static nonisolated func setValue<R>(_ key: String, _ newValue: Value)
    where Value == R?, R: RawRepresentable
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue?.rawValue, forKey: key)
    }

    static nonisolated func setValue(_ key: String, _ newValue: Value)
    where Value: UserDefaultsPropertyListValue
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
    }

    static nonisolated func setValue<R>(_ key: String, _ newValue: Value)
    where Value == R?, R: UserDefaultsPropertyListValue
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

`UserDefaultsPropertyListValue` is a protocol used to extend supported non-RawRepresentable types, e.g. Int, Bool, String, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Value` is redundant in this case.

```
func getUDValue<R>(_ key: String, _ defaultValue: R) -> R
where R: RawRepresentable
{
    guard let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? R.RawValue else {
        return defaultValue
    }
    return R(rawValue: rawValue) ?? defaultValue
}
```

You can just remove it and have the type be declared by the resulting property.

```
let res:Test23? = getUDValue("test", .test)
```

or

```
let res:Test23 = getUDValue("test", .test)
```

Comment: Rewriting it this way then uncovers something funky: this is needlessly hiding away the `??` logic. It would be better to just have it `func getUDValue<R>(_ key: String) -> R?` and leaving it to call to just call `??` themselves: `getUDValue("test") ?? .test`

Comment: @Alexander you are describing the standard form. There would be no point to the function. My guess is that the second use is more what the OP is aiming for or something like `let res  = getUDValue("test", Test23.test)` where there is no possibility of an optional. The optional is only possible if the parent variable is an optional.

Comment: This is for use in a swift macro, although I've done something similar for a property wrapper. When trying to work with generics and supporting optionals / enums, I have found that you need a method similar to my original post. It's worth noting that I solved the problem by putting it into a struct where the struct takes on <Value> and then the function uses the R method.

Comment: @loremipsum is right in that the function is overloaded to support different types, not just enums. Updated my post for the full solution. Default Values with optionals are odd since you would probably just use a non-optional, but it makes overloading easier and gives the flexibility to the end user should they desire to use an optional with default value.